# how to communicate non immediate child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, parent-child

I work on Change Detection in Angular.

I am looking at the methods like ***DoCheck*** and ***OnChanges***... 
To understand them, I made my application like below.

App1 - App2 - App3, App4, App5:

- App1 is a root component
- App1 has child component of App2
- App2 has child components of App3
- App4, and App5

I would like to log whenever the DoCheck and OnChanges are called in every component. And I would like to make App1 have all the logs.

For App1 and App2 to communicate is easy part.

I can make them interact each other with @Input and @Output however, I kind of struggle with how to make App1 get logs from App3, App4 and App5.

I think if I use @ngrx/store, it can be resolved easily, but I do not want to use it. What is the best way to do this from experts?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: there could be a few ways to do that... easiest way would be to create a loggerService, make it injectable, and then inject it in all components where you want logs. Call your custom logging method from where ever e.g. in your case ngDoCheck...

Comment: You can either have App2 subscribe to events from its children and push them up to App1 or create a service that they all use. Probably would do as @TypeScripter suggested and create a logging service.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you guys, I have a question to Daniel, what does it mean exactly by "push them up to App1"?